# Is there a proverb that describes a self-important person of low standing?

Tags: proverbs

For example, when someone thinks they rule the roost in a company, but in reality they don't have an important position.

Answer (score 3):

**Too big for his boots, or, alternatively, too big for his britches**

[Cambridge English Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/too-big-for-your-boots) says

> A person behaving as though he is more important than he is

This was a very common expression in the mid-20th century, but less so now.  It was often used to put sassy and self-important children in their place, but was also used for adults.   The Cambridge English Dictionary's example sentence referred to an adult:

> He's been getting a bit too big for his boots since he got that
> promotion.

Comment: Yeah, but that's an idiom. The OP specifically asks for a proverb.